# How to find which consumer is assigned to which partition of a topic in kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-zookeeper

I am building a `kafka manager tool` and I need to check which topic-partition is assigned to which consumer in a consumer group.

Suppose there is consumer-Group `group-A` consuming topic `topic-A` with `n partitions`, so there can be multiple consumers in `group-A` hosted in `different VM's`. So how to find which partitioned is assigned to which consumer host? Is it possible in `kafka 0.9.1`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kafka is primarily used to build real-time streaming data pipelines and applications that adapt to the data streams. It combines messaging, storage, and stream processing to allow storage and analysis of both historical and real-time data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check how `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` works and integrate its implementation into your `kafka manager tool`, this tool will show you detailed group owner information(for example, partition assignment, lag, IP).

GROUP                          TOPIC                          **PARTITION**  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             **OWNER**
 page_visits_10k                **0**          500             3333            2833            **consumer-1_/10.139.176.190**
 page_visits_10k                **1**          0               3334            3334            **consumer-1_/10.139.176.190**
 page_visits_10k                **2**          0               3333            3333            **consumer-1_/10.139.176.190**

Comment: Is there any API in JAVA to get it ?

Comment: consumer.assignment()

Answer (score 1):

I know it does not directly answer the question, but still relevant.

If you want to see the IP address of the consumer that is currently connected to a partition use the following command

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-1:9092 --group my-consumer-group  --describe --members
```

E.g.

```
# kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-1:9092 --group my-consumer-group  --members --describe --verbose | grep name-of-topic
my-consumer-group consumer-my-consumer-group-1-40adb273-fd3d-46a3-9cd4-9c8c4a4da486  /10.8.36.66     consumer-my-consumer-group-1  1               name-of-topic(1)
my-consumer-group consumer-my-consumer-group-1-47fc5618-7f07-4b3e-a2a9-cf3c26ee3536  /10.8.9.79      consumer-my-consumer-group-1  1               name-of-topic(2)
my-consumer-group consumer-my-consumer-group-1-005da938-7c59-44c3-8d4c-4371fa222d15  /10.8.36.22     consumer-pmy-consumer-group-1  1               name-of-topic(0)
```